# How can i solve this dont correct data?

Tags: mysql, node-red

[image]

```
flow.set("payload","msg.payload.payload");

flow.set("humidity","msg.payload.humidity");

var date = new Date().getTime();

msg.topic= "insert into sensor(temp, humidity, date) values('"+msg.payload.payload+"', '"+msg.payload.humidity+"', '"+date+"')";

return msg;
```

this is my function code

i receive data to `{"_msgid":"81665f152edd9336","payload":"25.20","topic":"rpi-dht22","humidity":"39.30","isValid":true,"errors":2,"sensorid":"dht22"}`

but saw in database `undefined, undefined, 1636534958644`
what is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems with the function node.

Firstly you are inserting strings into the `flow` context rather than the values from the incoming message, you should not be wrapping the value argument in quotes.

Secondly you have an extra `payload` in the `msg` object keys.

It should probably look like this:

```
flow.set("payload",msg.payload);
flow.set("humidity",msg.humidity);

var date = new Date().getTime();

msg.topic= "insert into sensor(temp, humidity, date) values('" 
   + msg.payload + "', '" 
   + msg.humidity + "', '" 
   + date + "')";

return msg;
```

Comment: thank you so much my problem is cleard for you

Comment: @이승훈 https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: this is my first question thank you for how i use this community